# Migrating to a new server & PHP version. json_decode() and unserialize() are failing

Tags: php, json, sql-server, serialization, character-encoding

I have a website that is currently running on SERVER1 with PHP v5.5.38. I am attempting to migrate it to a SERVER2 that is running PHP v7.4.33. I'm running into an issue that doesn't seem to be covered in the migration notes between the two versions of PHP.

I am using Databases with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation to store large blocks of JSON data in a text field. This data **does** contain foreign characters.

I have the same test PHP file on both servers that simply reads the JSON data from the database, and decodes it for display. On SERVER1 this works totally fine. On SERVER2, `json_decode()` fails giving me the error:

> Unexpected control character found

I am having the test page `echo` the raw data it is trying to decode. If I copy and paste that raw data into a JSON file, both servers read and decode that data properly.

I'm also storing the same data in serialized fashion using PHP's `serialize()` function and the same thing goes for the serialized data. Using `unserialize()` works just fine on SERVER1, but fails on SERVER2.

I am able to get the data to decode properly by running the following code on the raw data before trying to decode it:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) $data = str_replace(chr($i), "", $data); 
$data = str_replace(chr(127), "", $data);
```

But where are these random characters coming from? PHP v5 has no problem with this.

So clearly, the error is not with "malformed" JSON or Serialized data per-say --- but it is becoming corrupted somehow between the database and PHP. Has something changed in the odbc arena I am not aware of or can not find? I'm at a loss.

**Sample Code**

```
$data = $cache_db->getTextField("Select json From InstallationsCache where installation_id=1", 'json');
echo $data;

//Uncommenting this causes the decoding to function properly
//for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) $data = str_replace(chr($i), "", $data); 
//$data = str_replace(chr(127), "", $data);    

$data = json_decode($data, true, 512, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);
vardump($data);
```

**Stripped Down Database Class I am using**

```
<?php   
class DatabaseClass {
    public $connect;
    public $debug=false;
    public $server='';
    private $db_servers;
    
    public function __destruct(){ /* nothing to do*/ }
            
    public function __construct($server, $database){
        global $db_servers;
        $this->db_servers = $db_servers;
        $this->server = strtolower($server);
        try {
            return($this->openDB($this->db_servers[$this->server], $database));
        }catch(Exception  $e){
            return false;
        }
    }
    function closeDB(){
        odbc_close($this->connect);
    }
    
    function getTextField($sql, $field){
        $qt=odbc_exec($this->connect, $sql);
        $data = "";
        while (true) {
            $tText = odbc_result($qt, $field);
            if ($tText == "") break;
            $data.= $tText;
        }     
        return($data);                
    }

    function openDB($server, $db){
        global $localOnly, $me;
        try{
            $this->connect = @odbc_pconnect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=' . $server['addr'] . ', '.$server['port'].'; DATABASE='.$db, $server['user'], $server['pass']);
            if (!$this->connect) return false;
            return true;
        }catch (Exception $e){
            $this->connect = false;
            return false; 
        }
        //$this->connect = odbc_pconnect($dsn, $user, $pass);
    }               
}
?>
```

**Sample JSON with the VAST majority of items removed**

```
{
    "access_code_min": "4",
    "active": 1,
    "agent_term": "Agent",
    "agent_term_translations": {
        "EN": "Agent",
        "FR": "Agent",
        "GE": "Agent",
        "JA": "\u30a8\u30fc\u30b8\u30a7\u30f3\u30c8",
        "KO": "\uc5d0\uc774\uc804\ud2b8",
        "NL": "Tussenpersoon",
        "PL": "Agent",
        "RU": "\u0410\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0442",
        "SP": "Agente",
        "VI": "\u0110\u1ea1i l\u00fd",
        "zh-CN": "\u4ee3\u7406\u4eba",
        "zh-TW": "\u4ee3\u7406\u4eba",
        "zh_CN": "\u4ee3\u7406\u4eba",
        "zh_TW": "\u4ee3\u7406\u4eba"
    },
    "agents_term": "Agents",
    "agents_term_translations": {
        "EN": "Agents",
        "FR": "Agents",
        "GE": "Agenten",
        "JA": "\u30a8\u30fc\u30b8\u30a7\u30f3\u30c8",
        "KO": "\uc790\uce58\ub839 \ub300\ud45c",
        "NL": "agenten",
        "PL": "Agenci",
        "RU": "\u0410\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0442\u044b",
        "SP": "Agentes",
        "VI": "\u0110\u1ea1i l\u00fd",
        "zh-CN": "\u4ee3\u7406",
        "zh-TW": "\u4ee3\u7406",
        "zh_CN": "\u4ee3\u7406",
        "zh_TW": "\u4ee3\u7406"
    }
}
```

**Base64 JSON**

(Note, I am not entirely sure **this** chuck of the JSON is where the characters are)

CAgIHsNCiAgICAgICAgImFjY2Vzc19jb2RlX21pbiI6ICI0IiwNCiAgICAgICAgImFjdGl2ZSI6IDEsDQogICAgICAgICJhZ2VudF90ZXJtIjogIkFnZW50IiwNCiAgICAgICAgImFnZW50X3Rlcm1fdHJhbnNsYXRpb25zIjogew0KICAgICAgICAgICAgIkVOIjogIkFnZW50IiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJGUiI6ICJBZ2VudCIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiR0UiOiAiQWdlbnQiLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgIkpBIjogIlx1MzBhOFx1MzBmY1x1MzBiOFx1MzBhN1x1MzBmM1x1MzBjOCIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiS08iOiAiXHVjNWQwXHVjNzc0XHVjODA0XHVkMmI4IiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJOTCI6ICJUdXNzZW5wZXJzb29uIiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJQTCI6ICJBZ2VudCIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiUlUiOiAiXHUwNDEwXHUwNDMzXHUwNDM1XHUwNDNkXHUwNDQyIiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJTUCI6ICJBZ2VudGUiLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgIlZJIjogIlx1MDExMFx1MWVhMWkgbFx1MDBmZCIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiemgtQ04iOiAiXHU0ZWUzXHU3NDA2XHU0ZWJhIiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJ6aC1UVyI6ICJcdTRlZTNcdTc0MDZcdTRlYmEiLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgInpoX0NOIjogIlx1NGVlM1x1NzQwNlx1NGViYSIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiemhfVFciOiAiXHU0ZWUzXHU3NDA2XHU0ZWJhIg0KICAgICAgICB9LA0KICAgICAgICAiYWdlbnRzX3Rlcm0iOiAiQWdlbnRzIiwNCiAgICAgICAgImFnZW50c190ZXJtX3RyYW5zbGF0aW9ucyI6IHsNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJFTiI6ICJBZ2VudHMiLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgIkZSIjogIkFnZW50cyIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiR0UiOiAiQWdlbnRlbiIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiSkEiOiAiXHUzMGE4XHUzMGZjXHUzMGI4XHUzMGE3XHUzMGYzXHUzMGM4IiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJLTyI6ICJcdWM3OTBcdWNlNThcdWI4MzkgXHViMzAwXHVkNDVjIiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJOTCI6ICJhZ2VudGVuIiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJQTCI6ICJBZ2VuY2kiLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgIlJVIjogIlx1MDQxMFx1MDQzM1x1MDQzNVx1MDQzZFx1MDQ0Mlx1MDQ0YiIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiU1AiOiAiQWdlbnRlcyIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiVkkiOiAiXHUwMTEwXHUxZWExaSBsXHUwMGZkIiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJ6aC1DTiI6ICJcdTRlZTNcdTc0MDYiLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgInpoLVRXIjogIlx1NGVlM1x1NzQwNiIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiemhfQ04iOiAiXHU0ZWUzXHU3NDA2IiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJ6aF9UVyI6ICJcdTRlZTNcdTc0MDYiDQogICAgICAgIH0NCiAgICB9

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of the issue with relevant code and data?

Comment: I would love to. The problem is that when I copy and paste the data, the bad characters seem to disappear. I can add sample code I am using but the data would be tricky.

Comment: I did my best to provide what I have.

Comment: _"the bad characters seem to disappear"_ Try base64_encode on the raw string from the database and post that, that way we'll have the extra unprintables preserved.

Comment: Note that using serialize like that is fundamentally a bad idea. For instance, if you change a property on the class that was serialized, it could break unserializing older versions. It is not surprising at all that php 7 serializes things in a way that is not backward-compatible.

Comment: The collation used by the table is not necessarily the encoding of strings that reach your PHP code. Use [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to make sure you have an encoding you can work with.

Comment: When you say that the JSON is stored in a text field, do you mean that it's using the `text` data type that's been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005? Ref: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) _The ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead._

Comment: The posted data doesn't seem to be base64 encoded JSON. Do you have a different example?